# The pusher notification sound is not working in the Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, pusher

The pusher notification sound is not working in the Chrome browser.
I know that the order play () policy has changed. But how to bypass it and use the notification sound ??
I'm using Laravel 7
[Pictures of chrome browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbrFq.png)

[Here is my Vue js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2cIB.png)

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["dataAuthUser"],
  data() {
    return {
      unreadNotifications: "",
      //   readNotifications: "",
      user: JSON.parse(this.dataAuthUser),
      alart: new Audio("/alert/alert.mp3"),
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("/admin/vue-notify")
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res);
        this.unreadNotifications = res.data.unreadNotifications;
        // this.readNotifications = res.data.readNotifications;
        // this.playSound();
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
    console.error(err);
  },
  mounted() {
    Echo.private("App.User." + this.user.id).notification((notification) => {
      this.unreadNotifications.unshift(notification);
      return this.alart.play();
    });
  },
  methods: {},
  watch: {},
};
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please add code in post instead of Imgae of code editor.

Comment: I have added vue js code. Please see the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this method will help you.[First of all click the site information tab of your specific site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Pb9.png)

[then go to the site settings and allow the Sound of that site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdEWv.png)

Comment: Yea. It's working but I need JavaScript bypass notifications